# How to use ggplot2's geom_dotplot() with both fill and group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I really like the way the `ggplot2::geom_dotplot()` can nicely stack dots towards the middle of a category but I cannot seem to combine that with a fill color.

Lets take a look at an example:

```
# test data
tmpData <- data.frame(x=c(rep('x', 3),rep('y', 3)), y=c(1,1,2,1,2,2), fill=rep(c('A', 'B', 'B'), 2))

# Plot without fill color
ggplot(tmpData, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize=4)
```

Resulting in this plot:

[image: Dotplot without color]

But when I add the fill argument:

```
ggplot(tmpData, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=fill)) +   
   geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize=4)
```

The fill seems to overwrites the grouping done on "x" causing the two points (x, 1)(x, 1) to be collapsed I would like them to have different colors.

[image: Dotplot with color]

When I try to specify the group the fill color is ignored:

```
ggplot(tmpData, aes(x=x, y=y, group=x, fill=fill)) +
    geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize=4)
```

[image: Dotplot with group specified]

The collapsing seems to be avoidable by enabling stackgroups:

```
ggplot(tmpData, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=fill)) +
    geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackgroups=TRUE, stackdir = "center", dotsize=4)
```

[image: dotpoot with stackgroups]

But then I lose the centering of the data to the "x" and "y" that are found in the other 3 plots.

Is there a way to use `geom_dotplot()` with both groups and fill?

Comment: I can confirm that this problem still arises in `ggplot2 1.0.1`, and I've raised an issue with Hadley to that effect: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1359

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're open to a bit of a hacky solution just to get it how you want it to look... You can overwrite the fill command by simply providing it with a vector of color names:

```
tmpData$colorname <- rep(c('red','blue','blue'),2)

ggplot(tmpData, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize=4, fill=tmpData$colorname)
```

[image]

Comment: How would you go about adding a legend with this method?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add the argument `position = "dodge"`:

```
 ggplot(tmpData, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill,)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = 4, position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: I did try it but this solution removes the nice centering of the dots around "x" and "y" (just like stackgroups=TRUE).

Comment: @Kristoffer Vitting-Seerup It's not exactly the same as stackgroups=TRUE, they are symmetrically plotted, group A to the left and B to the right o fhe vertical axes x and y. So groups are aligned whereas in your example they are not.

Comment: True, but that is not what I wanted to do.
I wanted them centered just as in the first plot, just with the color added :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `stackdir ="center"` with `binpositions = "all"` and `stackgroups = TRUE`. This will do the work as it worked for me.
`binpositions = "all"` determines positions of the bins with all the data taken together; this is used for aligning dot stacks across multiple groups.

```
library(ggplot2)
# test data
tmpData <- data.frame(x=c(rep('x', 3),rep('y', 3)), 
                      y=c(1,1,2,1,2,2), fill=rep(c('A', 'B', 'B'), 2))

# Plot without fill color
ggplot(tmpData, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize=4)

# After adding fill
ggplot(tmpData, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=fill)) +   
geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir = "center", binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE,dotsize=4)
```

Here is the image produced by this code

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Here at SO code only answers are **not considered good answers**, though, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. Answers with an explanation are always more helpful. The solution may be obvious to you. To others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from existing answers. Otherwise this answer may be flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality).

Comment: Thank you for guiding me. I've added an explanation of what I used in my code different from the existing answers.