# How can I get colored dotplots by group in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble coloring grouped dotplots with these data (oddly, I can't reproduce the problem with one of the datasets that ships with `ggplot2` so I apologize for the extra step).

```
data <- data.frame(
  Period = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L),
  Rate = c(0, 10, 10, 100, 20, 10, 20, 10, 5, 100, 0, 50, 50, 100, 20, 100, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 50, 10, 100, 15, 50, 0, 0, 5, 0, 100, 50, 0, 100, 0, 50, 0, 0, 5, 0, 100, 100, 50, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 0, 100, 10, 100, 0, 0, 100, 0, 10, 5, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 10, 5, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 30, 10, 10, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 10, 100, 50, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 10, 20, 100, 100, 100, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 100, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 20, 0, 0, 20, 100, 10, 0, 0, 100, 100, 30, 0, 0, 10, 100, 0, 0, 0),
  Subject = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "3", "5", "6")
)
g <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = factor(Period), y = Rate, fill = Subject, group = Period))
g + geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")
```

[image: dotplot]

This is all fine, **except that oddly, the dots don't retain the `fill=Subject` color**.

How can I color them by `Subject`?

**Update**

*Without*  `group = Period`, was was suggested in the comments, fill color is retained, but there is not a real dotplot – all dots overlap.

[image: nongrouped]

Comment: you just need to remove `group = Period`

Comment: yes, but without `group = Period`, it's not a real dotplot – they all overlap. See updated question.

Comment: does `position = "dodge"` help?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT2** It appears that this question has also been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557973/how-to-use-ggplot2s-geom-dotplot-with-both-fill-and-group). I've flagged the question as a duplicate hereof.

Using `fill` directly in `geom_dotplot` seems to work:

```
data$Period <- as.factor(data$Period)
g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Period, y = Rate, fill = Subject, group = Period))
g + geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", 
                 fill = data$Subject)
```

[image]

Obviously, the `fill` in `ggplot` might then be obsolete.

**EDIT**

Adding `position = "dodge"` and omitting `group = Period` also produces a similar plot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(Period), y = Rate, fill = factor(Subject))) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", position = "dodge", binwidth = 2)
```

[image: image2]

Is this it?

Comment: mmh yes, but then the legend disappears (and colors would have to be manually colored, correct?)
I just don't understand why `geom_dotplot` does not respect the `fill = Subject` aesthetic mapping in this case, which it is *supposed* to understand as per the docs: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_dotplot.html

Comment: @maxheld The `position = "dodge"` then seem to do the trick? I've edited my answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: @maxheld I've flagged the question as duplicate of [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557973/how-to-use-ggplot2s-geom-dotplot-with-both-fill-and-group) Hope that helps-it seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try `geom_jitter`

```
g + geom_jitter(binwidth = 1, binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", aes(group = Subject, color = Subject), size = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: yes, I tried that too, thanks – it's very close, but not a real dotplot.
I just don't understand why `geom_dotplot` won't accept the `fill = Subject` aesthetic mapping in this case, though it is documented to do so.