# geom_dotplot() loses dodge after applying colour aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, fill

I want to organize my data by one category on the X-axis, but color it by another category as in this example:

**Graph 1, without coloring:**

```
require(ggplot2)
nocolor <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=disp)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir = "center")
print(nocolor)
```

[image]

**Graph 2, with coloring:**

```
nododge <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=disp, fill=as.factor(gear))) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir = "center")
print(nododge)
```

[image]

One problem that occurs after introducing coloring is that the dots belonging to different groups wont dodge one another anymore. This causes problems with my real data, as I get dots that happen to have the same value and completely obscure one another.

Then I tried this, but it garbled my data:

**Graph 3:**

```
garbled <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=disp)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir = "center", fill=as.factor(mtcars$gear))
print(garbled)
```

[image]

The dots dodge one another, but the the coloring is just random and is not true to the actual data.

I expected the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557973/how-to-use-ggplot2s-geom-dotplot-with-both-fill-and-group) to solve my problem, but the coloring remained random:

Graph 4:

```
graphdata <- mtcars
graphdata$colorname <- as.factor(graphdata$gear) 
levels(graphdata$colorname) <- c("red", "blue", "black")
jalapic <- ggplot(graphdata, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=disp)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir = "center", fill=as.character(graphdata$colorname))
print(jalapic)
```

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to get the dots in Graph #2 to dodge one another, or how to fix the coloring in graphs 3 or 4? I would really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: in Graph#2, you can do `geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir = "center", position="dodge")`

Comment: That segregates each coloring group on a separate x-axis, which is not the look I am aiming for. I want the dots to be still clustered within the same pile, but identifiable by color. My problem is actually exactly the same as Kristoffer Vitting-Seerup's, which was very accurately described in the question under this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557973/how-to-use-ggplot2s-geom-dotplot-with-both-fill-and-group). I somehow couldn't get the solution in jalapic's answer to work for me though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `binpositions = "all"` and `stackgroups = TRUE`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=disp, fill=as.factor(gear))) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir = "center", binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE)
```

gives:

[image]

A possible alternative is using `stackdir = "up"`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=disp, fill=as.factor(gear))) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir = "up", binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE)
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: This is much better than where I started, thank you! I was able to replicate this with my original data. However, it looks a little weird. It looks like puzzle pieces taken apart from one another. It's a little more visible when you try it with the mpg variable of the mtcars data:

`ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill=as.factor(gear)))+ geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir = "center", binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE) `

Do you mind trying this and letting me know if there is a solution to the weird look? Otherwise, I am ok with the answer you already gave.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option that might work better than a dotplot, depending on your needs. We plot the individual points, but we separate them so that each point is visible.

In my original answer, I used `position_jitterdodge`, but the randomness of that method resulted in overlapping points and little control over point placement. Below is an updated approach that directly controls point placement to prevent overlap.

In the example below, we have `cyl` as the x variable, `disp` as the y variable, and `gear` as the colour aesthetic.

- Within each `cyl`, we want points to be dodged by `gear`.
- Within each `gear` we want points with similar values of `disp` to be separated horizontally so that they don't overlap.

We do this by adding appropriate increments to the value of `cyl` in order to shift the horizontal placement of the points. We control this with two parameters: `dodge` separates groups of points by `gear`, while `sep` controls the separation of points within each `gear` that have similar values of `disp`. We determine "similar values of `disp`" by creating a grouping variable called `dispGrp`, which is just `disp` rounded to the nearest ten (although this can, of course, be adjusted, depending on the scale of the data, size of the plotted points, and physical size of the graph).

To determine the x-value of each point, we start with the value of `cyl`, add dodging by `gear`, and finally spread the points within each `gear` and `dispGrp` combination by amounts that depend on the number of points within the each grouping.

All of these data transformations are done within a `dplyr` chain, and the resulting data frame is then fed to `ggplot`. The sequence of data transformations and plotting could be generalized into a function, but the code below addressed only the specific case in the question.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dodge = 0.3  # Controls the amount dodging
sep = 0.05   # Within each dodge group, controls the amount of point separation

mtcars %>% 
  # Round disp to nearest 10 to identify groups of points that need to be separated
  mutate(dispGrp = round(disp, -1)) %>%
  group_by(gear, cyl, dispGrp) %>% 
  arrange(disp) %>%
  # Within each cyl, dodge by gear, then, within each gear, separate points
  #  within each dispGrp
  mutate(cylDodge = cyl + dodge*(gear - mean(unique(mtcars$gear))) + 
           sep*seq(-(n()-1), n()-1, length.out=n())) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=cylDodge, y=disp, fill=as.factor(gear))) + 
  geom_point(pch=21, size=2) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)))
```

[image]

Here's my original answer, using `position_jitterdodge` to dodge by color and then jitter within each color group to separate overlapping points:

```
set.seed(3521)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=disp, fill=as.factor(gear))) + 
  geom_point(pch=21, size=1.5, position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=1.2, dodge.width=1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This was an alternative I had in mind, which I had not tried yet. Nice to see it work, thank you! However, is there a way to have the dots completely dodge one another? I tried increasing jitter.width, which spread the dots out too much without completely eliminating overlap.
I would want to have them completely dodge one another so that I can increase alpha to 1. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use a smaller point size and more jitter. It will probably be difficult to get complete separation of all points while still using a small enough dodge to prevent overlap of x-axis categories, but you can play around with it an see if you can get something you like.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new method that avoids overlap of the individual points.