# How to actually center geom_dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in different categories that I want to show with a dotplot. Even though the stack direction is "center", the dots are not always centered. I think some aspect of the positioning is "carrying on" across categories. But I don't know how to prevent it.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
library(tidyverse)

data = data.frame(
  x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  y = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  color = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
)

ggplot(data) +
  aes(x = factor(x), y = y, fill = factor(color)) +
  geom_dotplot(
    binaxis = "y", 
    dotsize = 1, 
    stackdir = "center", 
    stackgroups = TRUE, # prevent dots from overlapping
    binpositions="all")
```

And the output:

[image]

The yellow highlight shows the off-center part.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31557973/2572423

Comment: It's close. It appears the issue referenced in that question was closed but not fixed. Here's the new issue https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1745