# mis-aligned points in geom_dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dotplot, but for some reason, not all of my points are aligned along the centre.  Instead, these points seem to "float" above the centre grid line for each category.  How can I adjust their location?

[image]

**Code for present figure:**

```
ggplot(data = filter(lastDet,
                     !ID %in% c("NB2015.341", "NB2018.7", 
                                "NB2018.43", "NB2018.45")),
       aes(x = speciesEN, y = yday(depDate))) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = factor(year), colour = factor(year)), 
               binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', dotsize = 0.7,
               stackgroups = TRUE, 
               binpositions = "all", 
               method = "histodot") +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point",
               colour = "black", shape = 4, size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(181, max(yday(lastDet$depDate))),
                     breaks = c(181, 196, 212, 227, 243),
                     labels = c("1 Jul", "15 Jul", "1 Aug",
                                "15 Aug", "1 Sep")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("white", "white", "white"),
                      guide = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CA3542", "#FEBC38", "#849FAD")) + 
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = "Departure date", 
       x = "", 
       fill = "Year") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

EDIT:

"hacky" solution provided in duplicate question will not work for my larger data frame.

EDIT 2:

As requested, here's a subset of my dataframe.  I've attempted to make it as representative as possible.

```
dput(lastDet.sub)
structure(list(speciesEN = c("Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", 
"Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", 
"Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", 
"Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", 
"Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", "Barn Swallow", 
"Barn Swallow", "Cliff Swallow", "Cliff Swallow", "Cliff Swallow", 
"Cliff Swallow", "Cliff Swallow", "Cliff Swallow", "Cliff Swallow", 
"Cliff Swallow", "Cliff Swallow", "Cliff Swallow", "Tree Swallow", 
"Tree Swallow", "Tree Swallow", "Tree Swallow", "Tree Swallow", 
"Tree Swallow", "Tree Swallow", "Tree Swallow", "Tree Swallow", 
"Tree Swallow"), year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018
), depDate = structure(c(1531737145.3837, 1534093849.7991, 1530997725.9412, 
1531076069.5422, 1533041446.3001, 1531076076.231, 1533032604.2326, 
1534086023.11, 1531737149.7107, 1532882823.5637, 1406899801.4133, 
1406297348.1112, 1407276094.4158, 1405278154.7126, 1406330632.0613, 
1407490305.4993, 1406370738.3239, 1406655731.0996, 1406552025.8514, 
1406366734.892, 1405371083.9787, 1405935159.2899, 1406656817.3111, 
1405964739.2527, 1405935269.2718, 1407405240.0903, 1406416984.3628, 
1407078925.0925, 1406201767.0139, 1406285074.475, 1407362335.7969, 
1405886217.5548, 1406586545.9097, 1406123078.5834, 1439577132.3188, 
1439594526.7378, 1438097832.985, 1438097743.3089, 1438470481.0184, 
1438246572.18, 1438252727.6824, 1436190169.4567, 1438595642.3985, 
1438728341.4292, 1437298553.0341, 1437573409.4331, 1439402462.271, 
1437577437.0105, 1438209133.1853, 1438006270.5975, 1438424815.9509, 
1438260465.2748, 1439561952.8794, 1441068339.0791, 1437322842.1042, 
1438794640.5246, 1439673494.5053, 1439825890.7982, 1438173337.2322, 
1438805137.1318, 1438083434.1402, 1436372532.3594, 1435960025.2834, 
1439508786.8144, 1439668992.4789, 1439545490.7975, 1438962415.0014, 
1437768970.3123, 1438423416.3447, 1438251288.8178, 1439757591.1317, 
1437844819.4679, 1438247033.9429, 1439141690.47, 1438207292.6573, 
1438171703.2655, 1438277212.7584, 1439199695.1607, 1534507807.6186, 
1532702235.5266, 1533820579.7317, 1532957266.8756, 1531824345.5634, 
1532598380.2699, 1532098828.52, 1533568517.8915, 1533407138.0839, 
1535885104.009, 1533305719.4551, 1535042919.6962, 1533555209.5058, 
1535132109.2126, 1534526297.7543, 1535543329.7974, 1535797758.1752, 
1535538134.3428, 1535279656.0938, 1532184581.5469, 1534778864.0948, 
1534708212.9832, 1534862676.3394, 1535027042.7154, 1534936249.3542, 
1535211828.7767, 1534936232.9197, 1535227479.6166, 1534506480.411, 
1533161753.2014, 1533115007.6647, 1531570748.0769, 1533673583.6144, 
1533201700.8021, 1531239978.3688, 1531843656.4454, 1532604093.761, 
1530790685.643, 1531132089.8288, 1530533431.1395, 1530787169.1414, 
1530471991.9423, 1530643624.7047, 1530474331.461, 1531679979.9343, 
1531673724.9375, 1531579988.1816, 1531394352.5095, 1531831107.0235
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -127L))
```

Comment: Hi @Tung, my df has over 9 million records in it, but I'll try to come up with an example for you.

Comment: @camille, geom_dotplot is a function in ggplot2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ggplot2's geom\_dotplot() with both fill and group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557973/how-to-use-ggplot2s-geom-dotplot-with-both-fill-and-group)

Comment: Duplicate has only a hacky solution; open issue here: [geom_dotplot dot layout with groups #1745](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1745)

Comment: @PoGibas, I have a lot more data, so the 'hacky' solution won't really work for me.

Comment: (@Gregor wow yup, I'm embarrassed.) OP, you'll need to post a representative sample of data for us to really help, especially if a solution that's been suggested doesn't work for you. Doesn't need to be anywhere near your actual 9 million rows

Comment: @camille  I hope the put info above will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use `geom_dotplot` often, so I can't claim to be the most familiar with it. But based on the sample data, it seems like faceting by x and assigning each x value to a different facet panel could fix the alignment problem. See if this works for your large data frame?

```
# original plot as per question, other than the data portion since lastDet has no ID to filter
p1 <- ggplot(data = lastDet,
            aes(x = speciesEN, y = yday(depDate))) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = factor(year), colour = factor(year)), 
               binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', dotsize = 0.7,
               stackgroups = TRUE, 
               binpositions = "all", 
               method = "histodot") +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point",
               colour = "black", shape = 4, size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(181, max(yday(lastDet$depDate))),
                     breaks = c(181, 196, 212, 227, 243),
                     labels = c("1 Jul", "15 Jul", "1 Aug",
                                "15 Aug", "1 Sep")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("white", "white", "white"),
                      guide = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CA3542", "#FEBC38", "#849FAD")) + 
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = "Departure date", 
       x = "", 
       fill = "Year") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

# alignment fixed by facet
p2 <- p1 + 
  facet_grid(forcats::fct_rev(speciesEN) ~ .,     # use fct_rev to reverse factor levels & match
                                                  # x-axis order (can replace with simply
                                                  # `speciesEN ~ .`, if this isn't needed)
             scales = "free", space = "free") +   
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"))
```

[image: p2]

By default, each facet panel has the same size. The number of dots in the same position doesn't affect scale limits, so setting `space = "free"` in `facet_grid` won't change the amount of space allocated to each facet. Since the "Bank Swallow" facet panel has more dots with the same departure date than the others, I used a very generous height-width ratio in p2 to give sufficient space to each facet.

*But*, if we can't afford such generous panel sizes, we can also calculate the maximum number of dots manually:

```
rel.width <- layer_data(p2) %>%
  select(PANEL, y, fill, colour, count) %>% 
  unique() %>%
  group_by(PANEL, y) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
  summarise(count = max(count),
            y = mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  rename(speciesEN = PANEL)
levels(rel.width$speciesEN) <- rev(sort(unique(lastDet$speciesEN)))

> rel.width
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  speciesEN     count     y
  <fct>         <dbl> <dbl>
1 Tree Swallow      2  192.
2 Cliff Swallow     3  200 
3 Barn Swallow      5  229.
4 Bank Swallow     12  210.
```

And add this as an invisible layer to the plot in order to force each facet to adjust its space:

```
p3 <- p2 +
  geom_tile(data = rel.width,
            aes(y = y, width = count, height = 1),
            alpha = 0)
```

[image: p3]

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this fix.  the plot looks so much better now and I really appreciate the time and effort that went into your thoughtful and helpful answer.