# ggplot2 - how to align geom_dotplot with x-axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have generated the dot plot below using ggplot2. However, the dots are not aligned with their respective experiments (except for the first one). How do I get them aligned?

This is the script I used:

```
emibc_plot <- ggplot(emibc, aes(x = experiment, y = value, fill = model)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(seq(min(emibc$value), max(emibc$value), length.out=5), 0)), label= function(x) {ifelse(x==0, "0", scales::scientific_format(digits = 3)(x))}) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackgroups=TRUE, binpositions="all", dotsize = 0.5)
```

This is the output of `dput(emibc)`:

```
structure(list(model = c("CESM", "E3SM", "GISS", "MIROC", "CESM", 
"E3SM", "GISS", "MIROC", "CESM", "E3SM", "GISS", "MIROC", "CESM", 
"E3SM", "MIROC", "CESM", "E3SM", "GISS", "MIROC"), experiment = c("bc_no_seas", 
"bc_no_seas", "bc_no_seas", "bc_no_seas", "high_SO4", "high_SO4", 
"high_SO4", "high_SO4", "no_SO4", "no_SO4", "no_SO4", "no_SO4", 
"SO2_at_height", "SO2_at_height", "SO2_at_height", "SO2_no_season", 
"SO2_no_season", "SO2_no_season", "SO2_no_season"), value = c(2.13359e-16, 
2.13549e-16, 1.04680e-17, 2.86707e-16, 
3.97356e-20, 1.77632e-20, 0, 0, 2.22483e-20, 
1.17037e-20, 0, 0, 2.51571e-20, 9.81121e-21, 
0, 1.67484e-20, 1.46975e-20, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image: ggplot2 dot plot]

It may be worth noting that I get this warning when I run the script:

```
`stat_bindot()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

Comment: Can you please share data that is in the same structure as yours so that others can reproduce your problem?  e.g. including the output of `dput(emibc)` in the body of your question is a great way.

Comment: @JonSpring I've done that now, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some open issues in ggplot2's GitHub repository regarding this; see [1745](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1745) and [3620](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3620). There is also one pull request (which was closed and not merged) here: [1096](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/1096).

There is one hacky approach, though. From PR [1096](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/1096) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557973/how-to-use-ggplot2s-geom-dotplot-with-both-fill-and-group) you can pass the `fill` argument to `geom_dotplot()`. As user *vitorbl* mentions [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/1096#issuecomment-316443200), it seems your **data must be ordered first**.

```r
# required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# OP's data 
emibc <- structure(list(
  model = c("CESM", "E3SM", "GISS", "MIROC", "CESM", 
            "E3SM", "GISS", "MIROC", "CESM", "E3SM", 
            "GISS", "MIROC", "CESM", "E3SM", "MIROC",
            "CESM", "E3SM", "GISS", "MIROC"), 
  experiment = c("bc_no_seas", "bc_no_seas", "bc_no_seas",
                 "bc_no_seas", "high_SO4", "high_SO4", 
                 "high_SO4", "high_SO4", "no_SO4", 
                 "no_SO4", "no_SO4", "no_SO4", "SO2_at_height",
                 "SO2_at_height", "SO2_at_height", "SO2_no_season", 
                 "SO2_no_season", "SO2_no_season", "SO2_no_season"), 
  value = c(2.13359e-16, 2.13549e-16, 1.04680e-17, 
            2.86707e-16, 3.97356e-20, 1.77632e-20,
            0, 0, 2.22483e-20, 1.17037e-20, 0, 0,
            2.51571e-20, 9.81121e-21, 0, 
            1.67484e-20, 1.46975e-20, 0, 0)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -19L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# order data
emibc <- emibc %>% 
  arrange(experiment, value)

# create a column with a color for each experiment
emibc <- emibc %>% 
  mutate(
    color =  case_when(
      model == "CESM" ~ "red",
      model == "E3SM" ~ "darkgreen",
      model == "GISS" ~ "lightblue",
      model == "MIROC" ~ "purple"
    )
  )

# make plot
ggplot(emibc, aes(x = experiment, y = value)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(seq(min(emibc$value), max(emibc$value), 
                                         length.out=5), 0)), 
                     label = function(x) {ifelse(x==0, "0", scales::scientific_format(digits = 3)(x))}) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = 0.5, 
               fill = emibc$color)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response, very helpful and informative!